# Як нормативно "скриншот" чи "скріншот"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Я вважала, що правильно писати *"скриншот"* (відповідно до [правила дев'ятки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)), проте сайт [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/skrinshot) подає слово, як *"скріншот"*. Можливо на сайті припустились помилки?!
Як правильно передати на письмі запозичене слово (переклад screenshot)?

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка, запитання. Є цілком собі нормативне правило «девʼятки». І є сайт без вихідних даних, де анонімні користувачі змагаються у словотворенні. Якщо ваше запитання «як правильно?» == «як нормативно?», то відповідь очевидна. Якщо «як правильно» == щось інше, то вкажіть, що са́ме.

Comment: погоджуюсь з паном bytebuster, https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0 - ось інше джерело, якому ми не надто довіряємо, пише все за правилом дев'ятки. Уточніть, будь ласка, в чому полягають ваші сумніви.

Comment: Див. також інше запитання: [«Український відповідник до слова „скриншот“»](/q/4561). Можливо, їх варто було б об'єднати в одне, але вони за змістом різні: це про правопис прямого запозичення, а те про спроби пошуку «ріднішого» еквівалента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильним є лише варіан "***скриншот***", оскільки це слово підпадає під ["правило дев’ятки", § 90, п. 5, в-1](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=90-91), про яке Ви самі згадали:

> **И пишеться**:
> В загальних назвах **після** приголосних д, т, з, с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, **р перед наступним приголосним**: брига́да, риф, фа́брика та ін.

Такий же варіант пропонує нам і [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> Знімок екрану (англ. screenshot, **скриншот**).

Аналогічно і стверджує [О. Пономанів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-38442934):

> За так званим правилом дев'ятки, **потрібно вимовляти скриншот і писати разом**, а не з дефісом.

Однак, додам, що, чомусь, варіант "скрІншот" таки зафіксований у [Тлумачно-стилістичному словнику української мови, 2013](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> **Зня́ток**, -тка, чол.
>
> 3. комп., новотвір. Те ж саме, що й **скріншо́т**.